# How to access private class methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given a Class in Ruby:

```
class MyClass
  def self.my_class_method
    puts "class method"
  end

  private

  def my_method
    puts "regular method"
  end

  private_class_method :my_class_method
end
```

To access private methods I can call `.send(:my_method)` on the Class Object, but how does that work for class methods?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should do:

```
class MyClass
  def self.my_class_method
    puts "class method"
  end

  private

  def my_method
    puts "regular method"
  end

  private_class_method :my_class_method
end

# to call class method
MyClass.send :my_class_method # => class method
# to call instance method
MyClass.new.send :my_method # => regular method
```

In Ruby, class(s) are also objects, so you can call the `#send` method on the class also.

In Ruby, you can define **private class methods** as

```
class MyClass
  class << self
    private 

    def my_class_method
      puts "class method"
    end
  end
end
```

Or using thhis *macro* like method: [private_class_method](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/private_class_method)

Answer (score 6):

First off, `MyClass.send(:my_method)` would not work. You have to send it to an instance: `MyClass.new.send(:my_method)`.

Then, your `my_class_method` is not really private.
Ruby's semantic of `private` are somewhat different from what you might be used to in other languages. Since Ruby allows you to bypass encapsulation if you choose to, `private` just means that a method can only be called *implicitly*, without sending a message to an actual object.

For example:

```
class Example
  def test
    'foobar'
  end

  def hello
    puts test        # implicit receiver
    puts self.test   # explicit receiver
  end
end
```

This is all good, but why is this important for your question?
Because you're declaring `my_class_method` explicitly on `self`. Doing so **bypasses** the `private` modifier, and the method is public. This means that you can just call it with:

```
MyClass.my_class_method
```

If you really need `private` class methods, then you can define them on the metaclass:

```
class MyClass

  class << self

    private

    def my_class_method
      puts "class method"
    end
  end


  private

  def my_method
    puts "regular method"
  end

end
```

This will make `my_class_method` **actually** private, and force you to invoke it with any of these:

```
MyClass.send :my_class_method
MyClass.class_exec { my_class_method }
MyClass.class_eval { my_class_method }
MyClass.class_eval "my_class_method"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, that's not how you create a private class method.

```
class A
  private

  def self.foo
    "foo"
  end
end

A.foo # => "foo"
```

To create a private class method, you need to use [private_class_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-private_class_method).

```
class A
  def self.foo
    "foo"
  end

  private_class_method :foo
end

A.foo # => private method `foo' called for A:Class
```

Answer (score -1):

There are no such things as class methods. Class methods are just singleton methods of the class. But there are no such things as singleton methods either. Singleton methods are just instance methods of the singleton class. So, class methods are just instance methods of the class's singleton class.

Since there is no such thing as a class method, only instance methods, you already know what to do:

> To access private methods I can call `.send(:my_method)` on the Class Object, but how does that work for class methods?

Comment: > So, class methods are just instance methods of the class's singleton class.

Right. So...class methods!

Comment: Unfortunately, according to your definition, singleton methods of objects that are not classes are also class methods. For example: `foo = "Hello"; def foo.bar() "World" end; foo.bar #=> "World"`. Now, `bar` is a class method? BTW, I don't get why this is controversial. All I am saying is that since there are no class methods, only instance methods, and the OP says that he knows how to solve his problem for instance methods, he already knows how to solve his problem. And since he now understands that there are no class methods, only instance methods, whenever he runs into a similar problem …

Comment: … again, he already knows how to solve it without having to ask on [so].

Comment: Not really controversial, in the sense that this is a scemantics dissagreement - kind of a matter of opinion.

I beleive its both simpler, and non-confusing to call methods of class objects (descendants of the `Class` class) just "class methods", (or "class-level methods").
You don't need to distinguish them from methods of other singleton objects, so you don't need something to be called a "class method".

This is not "wrong" in my view. It's just harder to communicate and explain.

(On you comment, since this tring itteral is not an instance of Class, then `bar` is not a Class-method)

Comment: The thing is that the OP would never have needed to ask this question if he had known that class methods are actually instance methods, since he wrote that he knows already how to do this with instance methods.