# private and private_class_method keywords in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Why does `private` is applicable only for instance methods and isn't for the class methods? Not only that, why doesn't `private_class_method` method make the class methods private?

```
class Foo

  private

  def self.private_class_method
    puts 'hello from private_class_method'
  end


  def private_instace_method
    puts 'hello from private_instace_method'
  end
end

Foo.private_class_method #Ok!
Foo.new.private_instace_method #error: private method `private_instace_method' called for #<Foo:0x000001020873b8>
```

How about this?

```
class Foo

  private_class_method :private_class_method

  def self.private_class_method
    puts 'hello from private_class_method'
  end

  private

  def private_instace_method
    puts 'hello from private_instace_method'
  end
end

Foo.private_class_method #Ok!
Foo.new.private_instace_method #error: private method `private_instace_method' called for #<Foo:0x000001020873b8>
```

How do I make a class method private?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access private class methods in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27859296/how-to-access-private-class-methods-in-ruby)

Comment: Also, you should consider that `private_class_method` method name intersects with `private_class_method` class method http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-private_class_method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a private class methods like this:

```
class Foo
  def self.will_be_private
    # ...
  end
  private_class_method :will_be_private
end
```

Or like this:

```
class Foo
  class << self
  private
    def will_be_private
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

While it is possible the make a class methods private, I can hardly think of a good reason to do so. IMO a private class method is a code smell and indicates that there is a thing that should be extracted into it own class.

Comment: why does the first case produce an error `private_class_method': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)`?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Both versions work for me. Which version of Ruby do you use?

Comment: I mean, shouldn't the error have been `private method called`? it's 2.1.2p95

Comment: `wrong number of arguments` is a different error, that is raised if you try to call that method with arguments (the example does not accept arguments).

Comment: Ahhh, that's because it's titled `private_class_method` - the same as the Ruby's method.

Comment: Re: While it is possible the make a class methods private...
For the PFAAO pattern you don't want `:new` to be public.
https://kellysutton.com/2017/09/13/embracing-functional-programming-in-ruby.html